# How to remove an appended() image using jquery?

Tags: jquery

In my web application I have around 10 headings with same class name, so when a user click on that a loading image will be appended to them and some data will be filled via ajax in a div then after this whole processing i just want to remove that loading image.

Here is my code:

```
jQuery('.replyhead').live('click',function(){
    var idval=jQuery(this).attr('id');
    jQuery(this).append('<img src="images/loading.gif"/>');

    jQuery.post('abc.php',{rack:idval},function(data) {
        jQuery('#r'+idval).html(data);      
        //now here i just need to remove that loading.gif       
    });
});
```

Any recommendations on how to do this?

Comment: Fyi, if you write `jQuery` more than once you are doing something wrong. When wrapping your code in a document.ready event, use `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { ... });`; when not wrapping it, use `(function($) { ... })(jQuery);` - in both cases you can use `$` inside the function.

Comment: Additionally, you can simply use `this.id` to access the ID - no need to create another jQuery element just to get this value (actually, when using `$(this)` more than once in the same function, add something like `var $this = $(this);` and then use `$this`)

Comment: thanks,i will be more careful about it in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `append()` create an element using the `jQuery` constructor, use `appendTo` to append it. Later, you can use `img.remove()` (or whatever variable name you've chosen) to rmeove the image.

```
jQuery('.replyhead').live('click',function(){

    var idval = jQuery(this).attr('id');
    var img = jQuery('<img src="images/loading.gif"/>').appendTo(this);
    jQuery.post('abc.php',{rack:idval},function(data){
        jQuery('#r'+idval).html(data);      

        //Remove img
        img.remove();
    });
});
```

An alternative method would consist of attaching an unique ID to the image, and use `$("#uniqueIDhere").remove()` to remove the element. This method will break when you're not properly defining unique IDs though.

(Taken from the answer below, showing relevant parts only):

```
jQuery(this).append('<img id="loadinggif" src="images/loading.gif"/>');
    jQuery('#loadinggif').remove(); //This will FAIL if the function is executed twice
```

Answer (score 1):

Just give it an ID, and then remove it later:

```
jQuery('.replyhead').live('click',function(){
    var idval=jQuery(this).attr('id');
    jQuery(this).append('<img id="loadinggif" src="images/loading.gif"/>');

    jQuery.post('abc.php',{rack:idval},function(data) {
        jQuery('#r'+idval).html(data);      
        //now here i just need to remove that loading.gif       
        jQuery('#loadinggif').remove();
    });
});
```